# Is equivalent resistance always lower if we add a resistor to a passive electronic circuit?

Tags: resistance

How to prove that equivalent resistance of any passive network is always lower (or equal) if we add a resistor between arbitrary two nodes?

Note that this is not necessarily a parallel circuit, 2 nodes that we connect with a resistor are not the same 2 nodes between we want to measure equivalent resistance but completely arbitrary 2 nodes in passive network.

So imagine a circuit with 4 access points: A, B, C and D. We want to measure equivalent resistance between A and B. How can you prove that Rab will be less if we add a resistor between C and D?

I tried to search the web but didn't have any success.

To clarify, I am interested in equivalent DC resistance in an arbitrary network made of resistors only. How can we prove that the resistance Rab is not higher if we connect nodes C and D with any resistor?

tl;dr: 2 port network. Prove that connecting a load will reduce input resistance. In terms of [z-parameters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impedance_parameters#The_Z-parameter_matrix) we need a prof that \$ Z_{12} \cdot Z_{21} > 0 \$.

Comment: Sounds like homework. Explain what you've done so far and exactly where you're stuck. It's hard to create a good answer to an open ended question.

Comment: I don't think that you read the question correctly, it would be too hard for a homework, it is a theoretical question for any circuit (that can have a million nodes, branches and resistors inside).

Comment: You say "any passive network". Do you mean resistors only? What about capacitors or inductors? What about nonlinear passive elements? Are you talking about DC resistance only, or complex impedance in general?

Comment: DC only, so resistors only, sorry for not clarifying that earlier. Thanks for commenting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> To clarify, I am interested in equivalent DC resistance in an
>   arbitrary network made of resistors only. How can we prove that the
>   resistance Rab is not higher if we connect nodes C and D with any
>   resistor?

I believe it is the case that to increase Rab, the added resistor must be *in series* with any of the other resistors thereby *increasing* the resistance of that branch.

But, this would create a *new* node in the circuit.

Since your problem requires that the resistor be placed *across* two existing nodes, this added resistance is *in parallel* with the equivalent resistance between those nodes thereby *decreasing* the resistance of that branch.

---

To see that the Rab must decrease, consider terminals A & B to be port 1 and terminals C & D to be port 2 of a two-port network.

Looking into port 1, the equivalent resistance is, in terms of the [Z parameters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z_parameters):

\$ R_{ab} = z_{11} - \dfrac{z_{12}z_{21}}{z_{22}+R_L}\$

where \$R_L\$ is the resistance of the resistor to be connected across port 2  (here the impedances are all real and positive since this two-port is a network of resistors.)

Without the added resistor, \$R_{ab} = z_{11}\$ since \$R_L = \infty \$

For \$0 \leq R_L < \infty \$ , \$ R_{ab} < z_{11} \$

---

> Actually this is not a complete prof as we don't know that z12 and z21
>   are >0. How can we derive that? We actually just need a prof that
>   z21*z12 is greater or equal zero.

I quote from your problem statement:  *To clarify, I am interested in equivalent **DC** resistance in an arbitrary network **made of resistors only***.

Thus, we *do* know that all the impedance parameters, for a network of resistors only, are *real* and *positive*.

---

> Even if all elements are resistors z12 can be real and negative! For
>   example just change the direction of I2 and you will have new Z12 = -
>   old Z12.

The following *defines* the Z parameters.

[image]

\$ \begin{bmatrix} V_1 \\ V_2 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} z_{11} & z_{12} \\ z_{21} & z_{22} \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} I_1 \\ I_2 \end{bmatrix} \$

If you'll stop to think about this a bit, you should see that the Z parameters are real and positive for a resistor network.

For a worked example, see [this](http://www.egr.unlv.edu/~eebag/Chapter19.pdf).

Comment: Nope, that resistor (CD) is not necessarily in parallel with the Eq resistance Rab.

Comment: @serge, I didn't write that it was in parallel with Rab; you've misunderstood what I wrote.

Comment: I see. But I am not interested in resistance of that branch as of course it would just add a parallel resistance and eq resistance between c and d would be lower.

Thanks for commenting.

Comment: @serge, try thinking about it this way; if you *reduce* the value of *any* resistor in your network, is it possible that Rab *increases*?

Comment: No, but how to prove that? It is not as easy as it seems. Couldn't find a solution.

Comment: @Serge, the proof is straightforward if you'll think about your problem in terms of two-port network theory.  You're exposing four terminals of the network so you have a two-port network.  Consider the Z parameters for a bit and I think you'll have it:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impedance_parameters#Two-port_networks

Comment: Yep, I can see from impedance relations (when we connect a load). Thanks.

Comment: Actually this is not a complete prof as we don't know that z12 and z21 are >0. How can we derive that? We actually just need a prof that z21*z12 is greater or equal zero.

Comment: @Serge, nonsense.  See the addition to my answer.

Comment: I see the addition but it is not nonsense as you said. Even if all elements are resistors z12 can be real and negative! For example just change the direction of I2 and you will have new Z12 = - old Z12.

Comment: @Serge, see yet another addition to my answer.

Comment: I see your addition but still think that you are wrong. Just change access points CD to DC (so I2 goes into D instead of C) and you will have new z12 = - old z12.

Comment: @AlfredCentauri, see my answer for an example of a 2-port made entirely of resistors, with negative off-diagonal elements.

Comment: @ThePhoton, very well then, let me be more precise:  for any network composed of resistors and any two ports of that network, *there exist* real and positive z parameters for a choice of reference directions.  This is enough for the proof.

Comment: No, it's not because it doesn't mean that both Z12 and Z21 are positive in the same time. We know that they are only because of the reciprocity theorem so at the end it is not that easy as you thought as we need a proof for that theory. Anyways thank you Alfred and all others for the discussion, I really appreciate it.

Comment: @Serge, the reciprocity theorem tells us that the transimpedances are *equal* but all we need is that they have the same *sign*.  If you place a voltage source on port 1 with port 2 open, \$V_2 = \dfrac{Z_{21}}{Z_{11}}V_1\$.  Placing the same voltage source on port 2 and leaving port 1 open, \$V_1 = \dfrac{Z_{12}}{Z_{22}}V_2\$.  Clearly, if the transimpedances have different signs, *one of the gains will be positive while the other is negative.*.  Is that possible with a resistive network?

Answer (score 1):

My informal answer wouldn't probably satisfy a teacher, but I'd simply say: Let's see each connection between nodes as some kind of a path for a current to flow in the circuit. If there is no connection, resistance is infinite and current cannot flow. If we connect some nodes, we create a path between them to let the current flow. If we add more connections, we create more or wider paths to let more current flow there. Althoug it is called "resistor" and it creates "resistance", it actually creates a path for current. The biggest resistor is no resistor (no connection between nodes) at all.

Also, resistors are similar to roads for cars. Low resistance = wide road, high resistance = narrow road. If you build a new road between any two cities, you always increase traffic throughput. (Conversely, if you would build a new road in series with an existing road, you would then lower the traffic throughput.)

Comment: I don't need to satisfy a teacher because there are no teachers and uni days are long gone. Of course I understood intuitively why this is true but I was just wondering if there is a formal prof for that. Anyways I have my answer and formal prof is a derivation of Z-parameters when we have a load connected.

Answer (score 1):

To complete Alfred's proof, we have this, from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-port_network):

> A network is said to be *reciprocal* if the voltage appearing at port 2 due to a current applied at port 1 is the same as the voltage appearing at port 1 when the same current is applied to port 2. ... In general, a network will be reciprocal if it consists entirely of linear passive components (that is, resistors, capacitors and inductors). In general, it will not be reciprocal if it contains active components such as generators.

So, because your problem calls for all passive components in the network, you have a reciprocal network. I'll assume there's an unstated assumption that the elements are also linear, or we are working in a linearized small-signal approximation, because we're talking about Z-parameters.

Therefore *Z<sub>12</sub>* = *Z<sub>21</sub>* because that's what reciprocal means.

Therefore *Z<sub>12</sub>* and *Z<sub>21</sub>* have the same sign and *Z<sub>12</sub>Z<sub>21</sub>* >= 0.

**Edit**
Before I remove this answer since I essentially re-used it in the follow-up question, here's a trivial example of a 2-port network, made entirely of resistors, with negative *Z<sub>21</sub>*:

[image]

Here *Z<sub>21</sub>* is -100 Ohms.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback but do you know a prof that a network will be reciprocal if it consists entirely of linear passive components? 
I tried to prove that but it doesn't look easy at all. 
And because I am new in the community can you tell me if I can see why is my question marked down? Is it that electronic community here is not that friendly? And why everyone thinks that this is a homework, I don't remember that I was getting this types of homework when I was in uni as this doesn't look easy at all. It looks to me that it requires some matrix derivations and theorems.

Comment: This claims to "proove" it, but don't ask me to explain it without staring at it for an hour or so: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reciprocity_(electromagnetism)#Reciprocity_for_electrical_networks

Comment: As for why the downvote, I can't say. Somebody might have dv'ed because of the combination of it's a fairly tricky problem and your English is not perfect making it slightly more difficult to understand what you are asking (and somebody not being willing to take the effort to figure out what you're asking). I could certainly see this being asked as a homework in a university network theory class, so there's that aspect as well.

Comment: Given the "proof" goes back to Maxwell's equations and fundamental electromagnetics, you might also try this question at physics.stackexchange.com

Comment: His problem not only calls for passive components, it calls for the DC resistance of a network of resistors only.  While the reciprocal nature of the transimpedances of a passive network is important and generally relevant, *it's not needed for the case of a network of resistors only*.

Comment: It is needed because z12 can be negative, even if it is a network of resistors only.

Comment: @AlfredCentauri, I would not be surprised if there is a way to prove it without using reciprocity. But it's not correct that Z12 must be positive in a network of resistors...As Serge says, just reversing the connections of one of the ports into the nodes of the internal circuit will reverse the sign of Z12.

Comment: Incidentally, comments here may eventually be lost. I will probably delete this answer after a day or so, because it fits a lot better to Serge's follow-up question.

Comment: OK, I won't delete this, because the other question got closed. @Serge, you really should give the accept to Alfred (or one of the other answers), because he really did answer 80% of the problem, and I only wrapped up the last 20%.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like homework, so you should at least derive the equations by yourself.

1. In any case, for a mathematical proof, I would start by drawing all
   the possible resistance combinations inside the 4-node black box:
   Rab, Rac, Rad, Rbc, Rbd, Rcd.
2. Now take a pair of nodes, say A-B, and calculate the equivalent
   resistance. This will be a big and ugly equation.
3. Now, calculate the derivative of this equation with respect to Rcd.
   What this tells us is the exactly how will Rab change if we change
   Rcd.
4. By checking the monotonicity of this derivetive, you know EXACTLY
   whether a negative change of Rcd will result in a negative change in
   Rab.

Comment: This is not a homework, why do you think it is?
You cannot derive equation because I am interested in any passive circuit that can have a million branches, resistors and nodes inside. 
So how to prove that for any passive circuit Rab is not bigger if we connect nodes C and D?

Comment: I think this is a homework because it blatantly looks like one. I've done a few of these. Usually people don't care much for mathematical proofs otherwise. Anyway, if your circuit has N=100000 nodes instead of 4, it's not much different at all. You'll just have more combinations of node-to-node resistances, silly. That's how you prove it mathematically. If you want a *gut feeling*, intuitive understanding, then try imagining this: HOW could the resistance increase after putting a positive resistance in parallel? Give me ONE example of a linear circuit that will exhibit this behaviour.

Comment: No, I don't want a gut feeling or intuitive understanding because I had that already, that is why I formed the question in that way. 

And what example do you need from me? Like circuit with resistor of 1 Ohm and then you add another resistor of 1 Ohm.
You totally misunderstood the question if you think that it is as easy to prove this for a network with a million of nodes and a simple circuit. For a simple circuit you can just calculate everything but for an arbitrary circuit you don't have a final formula.

Comment: I didn't say that original circuit have only 4 nodes so I don't know why you said  "instead of 4"? That is why I think that you misunderstood the question. This has nothing to do with a parallel circuit. Anyways I got my answer, prof is actually a derivation of formulas for z parameters when you add a load to the other and.
I never ever had a homework like this, I was trying to solve another problem with infinite grid and was looking for lower bound which I can get by connecting some nodes.

Comment: If you add a resistor in series, you create a new node. Either you cannot understand your own problem statement, or your problem statement is incorrect.

Comment: You just misunderstood. You can have nodes C and D already connected internally through several nodes so adding a resistor between C and D will not be like adding a resistor in series. Anyway Alfred Centauri understood the problem and gave me the answer.

Comment: Adding a resistor between C and D will be like adding a resistor in parallel. That's my point. You said earlier that adding a resistor would result in an increase in resistance. And I replied that that would create a new node. Sorry, but I cannot shake off the feeling that you're not really reading what I'm writing here.

Comment: Opposite is true, I read what you wrote but it seems that you misread my comments. Adding will a resistor between C and D is not the same as adding a parallel resistor. Also where did I say that adding a resistor would result in an increase in resistance? I claim opposite and would like to know a mathematical proof for that. As it seems it is not that easy at all.

Comment: Adding a resistor between any two nodes is equivalent to adding a resistor parallel to something. As long as you don't create a new node, you're doing it all in parallel. Have you ever measured current with a multimeter?

Comment: Besides, you're all content with Z-parameters for no reason. They are just one of many possible mathematical representations of the same system.

Comment: But you are just stating obvious, of course any element of a circuit is parallel with the rest of a circuit but I cannot see how it can help us here. I am content with Z-parameters only because that was the closest we could get to solve this problem. You said that this looks like a homework so I guess that you have an easier approach for solving this problem? 
Thanks for the discussion.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is a relatively simple proof of this assertion. Apply a voltage, E, to terminals A and B.  Measure the current, I, being drawn from this voltage.  Then, by definition, the resistance between A and B is E/I.  Now consider terminals C and D.  Find the Thevenin equivalent voltage and resistance at these terminals with voltage E connected to terminals A and B. Denote them as Eth and Rth. If there is no added resistor at terminals C and D, then no current flows out of these terminals since the equivalent circuit consists of Eth in series with Rth and terminals C and D are open circuited.  If a resistor, Rcd, is connected to terminals C and D, then the equivalent circuit now consists of Eth in series with Rth and Rcd.  Then a current, Icd, will flow into resistor Rcd and equal to Eth/(Rth + Rcd).  This current is in addition to the current, I, that flowed into terminals A and B without Rcd connected. So now the resistance between terminals A and B is equal to E/(I + Icd) which is less than E/I.  Therefore the resistance between terminals A and B will be reduced if a resistor is added to terminals C and D.  Terminals C and D could be placed anywhere within the network so the proof holds for any resistor connected to any 2 terminals of the network.

Comment: "This current is in addition to the current, I, that flowed into terminals A and B without Rcd connected." 
Why?

Comment: @Serge  The existing network will continue to draw a current I because nothing in that network has changed.  Adding the resistor to terminals C and D has created a new current path that causes additional current to flow.  That's why the resistance looking into terminals A and B decreases.

Answer (score 0):

I have another way to prove it. We need to prove that every passive network with 2 ports has equivalent Pi or T configuration. After that it is easy to prove that placing a resistor on the output would reduce the input resistance.

By reducing number of nodes one by one we can reduce our network to Pi or T configuration.
We can do that by y-delta transform or [star-mesh transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star-mesh_transform).